# How to get recent X posts by category?

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I return the most recent X number of posts in a specific category?  I've looked at WP_Query() but not sure which parameters are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'category' => 1 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks.  The code executes but no matter which category I use, it always brings back the current page, which is where I'm testing the code.  Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: I'm using the correct catID and tried this on another page.  Still brings back the current page.

Comment: I updated my answer.  I just tested and works.  You should be able to put the category title in '' single quotes as well instead of the category id

Comment: Sorry - I was missing global $post in the original.  1st one works.  2nd doesn't get the very last post. The offset pushes it back by one.